# Android app isolation risks & implementation

Tags: mobile, sandbox

Are Android apps, specifically Chrome, isolated?

Can other apps listen to other apps' activity?

If so, how can apps be sandboxed?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://threatpost.com/side-channel-attack-android-weakness-likely-on-other-platforms) article. It is about side-channel attacks on Android apps through shared memory statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question.

First you can start by reading https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/ to get some feeling.

If you have experience with UNIX, then you will quickly see how the base of security in android works - every application has its own UID by default, which prevents it from doing may things to other applications on a system. This is basically THE application sandbox on Android (compare to desktop where every user application generally runs as the logged in user).

But of course all the inter-process communication still exists:

- files readable/writable by other applications
- UNIX domain sockets
- network sockets (if application has INET permission)
- any "classical IPC" (explicitly shared memory, semaphores...)
- Binder IPC (Activities, Services, Broadcast Receivers, Content Providers).

For all these it's application's responsibility to not allow arbitrary application to interface with it.

Then there are of course a bunch of side-channel attacks, like the one @lzam mentioned. You can also monitor process times, memory consumption. You might be able to get the activity that's currently displayed, see network connections from application, etc., etc.